# Why didn't Han Solo shoot Darth Vader's ship?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star

In the movie *Star Wars: A New Hope*, Han Solo in the Millennium Falcon decides to shoot one of the Darth Vader's wing man TIE fighters instead of shooting Darth Vader's TIE fighter. Is there a Star Wars canon explanation for this?

It seems to me that the most logical thing for Han Solo to do at that moment would have been to shoot the lead TIE fighter that is about to shoot at Luke's X-Wing fighter.

Comment: Did he know Vader is in the lead ship?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum, I don't know, yet that shouldn't matter because I think the most logical thing to do would be to destroy the lead fighter especially if you are attacking from above which Han did.

Comment: From watching the clip and the angle of the shot I don't think he could have possibly hit Vaders ship.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, from the clip I had watched, the Millennium Falcon is coming out of the sunlight and there is nothing but space and stars behind the Falcon indicating that he attacked from above the trench on the Death Star.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We see the scene from Han's perspective in the short animated film [*Han Solo - Taking flight for his friends*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Han_Solo_%E2%80%93_Taking_Flight_for_his_Friends). In short, Han (or rather Chewie since he's manning the guns from the cockpit) targets the *closest* ship. Our view suggests that their target appears to be pulling slightly ahead of Vader's ship (and in front of it, from Han's POV), meaning that it presents the cleanest shot.

Comment: @user255577 - Well, we know from TLJ that blaster shots can curve :-)

Comment: @ Valorum, don't get me started on TLJ, oy!

Comment: If you base it on this animated video, then this is the reason why he did what he did.

Comment: @user255577 - It's the best (canon) view we've got.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for finding and posting that video.